# GetFile List and copy from Remote server to local

Tags: c#

Thanks all for the suggestion made for my earlier query regarding to the getlist and copy.
I have only one issue here

String realname= "test" //am getting this value from Db,so is this anyway i can use like that rather than

string realname="*test*"//i know i can do like string realname="*"+Dbvalue+"*";

Am just wondering why it doesn't return anyvalue if don't use "*" ?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var getfiles = new fileshare.Program();

            string realname = "*test*";
            foreach (var file in getfiles.GetFileList(realname))
            {getfiles.copytolocal(file.FullName); }

            }
        private FileInfo[] GetFileList(string pattern)
        {
            var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\testserv01\dev");
            return di.GetFiles(pattern);
        }
        private void copytolocal(string filename)
        {
            string nameonly = Path.GetFileName(filename);
            File.Copy(filename,Path.Combine(@"c:\",nameonly));

        }
        }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a bit glib but really you need to start looking at the documentation of the functionality you are using: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx

that said the reason is that * is a wildcard - if you use "test" then you will only retrieve exact matches for "test".

the link above has some more examples.

Comment: In your example file is an instance of FileInfo.  FileInfo does not have "contains" method, note the only context I have to go on is the info in your post, based on that the questions you are asking don't make sense.  I'll take a guess that you are asking if you should perform a second match on the FileInfo[] that is returned by the DirectoryInfo search.  In that case the answer is No - you should make the wildcard search accurate - this is because the overhead of the file system search is gong to be incurred in both cases so you might as well avoid the overhead (& complexity) of second match